# Why are my fonts bold?

Tags: 11.04, fonts

Sorry for the large screenshot, but I wanted to include everything that's here:

[image: Screenshot]

Why are my fonts bold in *both* Chromium *and* Firefox?

(I have **not** modified any font settings in Chromium or Firefox; this is a fresh install.)

Comment: I can confirm I also have this problem, but also with Elementary OS (which is based off of 10.10).

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a problem with manual installation of fonts. Install MS fonts from `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package to ensure all font files are installed, and if you installed these fonts manually, remove them from your personal fonts folder (~/.fonts).

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome go to Preferences>Advanced>Web Content , you will be presented with the respective options to change them.
[image: Chrome]

I don't know 'bout Firefox though.

Comment: It's *not* an issue with either of the browsers, it's an issue with Ubuntu. (I didn't modify any browser settings, and they're not like this on older versions of Ubuntu.)

Comment: make sure that the fonts on the browsers match the fonts you're using with ubuntu

Comment: Irrespective of what other pages look like, the *Settings* page of Chromium **itself** has this problem. (I'm referring to the exact screenshot that you have: it's bold in my installation.) That's not something I can change from within Chromium.

Comment: Setting a different font than Segoe has the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

*I see this thread is almost two years old but I'm posting my workaround for others to use:*

I had the same exact problem with Chrome on Ubuntu 12.10. I installed the Roboto font in `~/.fonts` (all 16 fonts). Even though I set everything to "Roboto Light" under `gnome-tweak-tool`, Chrome was still using Black (or Bold).

**To fix it:** I deleted all Roboto fonts except for the Light variant and it started to work properly. Perhaps you should try this, removing the other variants of

Still unsure *why* Chrome did this, but perhaps it just sees "Roboto" has the font and picks the first file in the folder?

Comment: Deleting fonts is not the ideal solution, but thank you for sharing the option :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution for bold fonts in Google Chrome was

```
rm -rf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/roboto
```

I've installed the Roboto fonts myself a long time ago. The location should be the same if you haven't copied it manually. I'm using Mint 17.